# Download files from URL's in array naming them by items in another array

Tags: ruby

I have a CSV with two columns, I am pushing each column's data into an array. Column 2 contains URL's of images that I would like to download. How do I name the file it's corresponding value from column 1?

```
require "open-uri"
require "csv"
members = []
photos = []
CSV.foreach('members.csv', :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
    members << csv_obj[0]
    photos << csv_obj[1]
end
photos.each {
    |x| File.open({value from members array}, 'wb') do |fo|
        fo.write open(x).read
    end
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require "open-uri"
require "csv"
members = []
photos = []

CSV.foreach('members.csv', :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
    members << csv_obj[0]
    photos << csv_obj[1]
end

photos.each_with_index do |photo, index|
  File.open(members[index], 'wb') do |fo|
    fo.write open(photo) { |file| file.read }
  end
end
```

**Notes**:

1. Try to submit a snippet of the CSV file too, it will help testing the code.
2. The code assumes that the members array will contain file names with extension.
3. The reason for using the block with `open` while downloading file is so that to ensure closing of file stream.
4. I suggest to use long descriptive variable names; it silently documents your intent and makes code very readable.
5. `wb` argument in `File.open` method is to ensure writing the file in binary mode.

Comment: That's the ticket! I knew I was going to have to do something with index, but seeming as I started learning Ruby about 30 minutes ago I was lost. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure :), great language to learn! You will be delighted as you keep discovering more of its beauty.